# jquery window resize function only triggering once instead of at every resize

Tags: jquery, html, resize, window

I am trying to set up a jquery function that checks window width in order for a navigation bar to work properly. What I want to happen is this: If the screen width is **larger** than 949px, initiate a function that that makes hovering on a .dropdown anchor link open up a dropdown sub menu; if the screen width is **less than or equal to** that 949px, remove that function so that the .dropdown anchor link must be clicked on in order to open the dropdown sub menu (the dropdown links open by default when clicking them- I think this is a bootstrap component).

I created a few functions based on some similar examples I found on stackoverflow but have found that the function only triggers once the screen width has surpassed 949px, so at smaller widths the .dropdown anchors are still opening submenus via hover which is what I don't want.

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(this).width()>949){
    $(".dropdown").hover(function(){
      $(this).addClass("open");
    },
    function(){
      $(this).removeClass("open");
    });
  }
});
```

How can I improve this function so that the .dropdown hover functionality is added at widths above 949px and removed at 949px and below?

Comment: Just want to make sure: var a - b; Is that syntax correct or just a typo?

Comment: I see you adding the hover event to the .dropdown boxes when the size is bigger than 949, but don't you want to remove that listener once the size is less? I'm not very accustomed to the jquery way, but Im certain it has functions to remove an event listener: take a look at on() and off()

Comment: Hey- you're right, that was a typo which has been edited. I'm not entirely sure how to revise my script with your suggestion... my thinking is that both functions (add hover or remove hover) are dependant upon "on" change events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than adding and removing bindings, just establish the event binding and check the size before doing anything:

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 949) {
        $(this).addClass("open");
    }
}, function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 949) {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
});
```

If you add and remove the event handler, you need to prevent doing it twice (e.g. they resize to 980 and then resize to 1050).

```
var hover_added = false;

$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    if (width > 949 && !hover_added) {
        $(".dropdown").on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass("open");
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("open");
            }
        });
        hover_added = true;
    } else if (width <= 949 && hover_added) {
        $(".dropdown").off("mouseenter mouseleave");
        hover_added = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response Barmar. This code is close, but anytime I change the screen width from being less than 950px up to 950px and beyond, the hover functionality stops working.

Comment: I forgot to clear `hover_added` when removing the handler.

Answer (score 0):

probaply not perfect, since jquery is not my forte, but it does the job:

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(this).width()>949){
    $(".dropdown").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).addClass("open");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        }
    });
  }
  else{
    $(".dropdown").off("mouseenter");
    $(".dropdown").off("mouseleave");
  }
});
```

Be aware that this implementation will remove any other existing mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers on the .dropdown elements as well.

Comment: Thank you for the responses elfwyn. This seems to be working better, I'll see if I can build on it.

Comment: Take Barmars code, since it prevents overhead and is more refined than my sollution.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is (in order to avoid to bind more times the same event):

```js
var width = $(window).width();

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  doResize(e);
});

function doResize(e) {
  if ($(this).width()>949) {
    var isOpenOnHover = $('.dropdown-toggle').data('isOpenOnHover');
    if (isOpenOnHover) {
      return;
    }
    $('.dropdown-toggle').data('isOpenOnHover', true);
    $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function () {
      $('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click.bs.dropdown');
    });
  } else {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').data('isOpenOnHover', false);
    $('.dropdown-toggle').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').data('isOpenOnHover', false);
  doResize();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank your for your response but I'm opting for the above answer since I already have it working.